# How do I login to a website from Android?

Tags: android, authentication

I have 2 textboxes and a button how do I log into a website? If the user and password are wrong then it should give an error.

Comment: Could we have some more information? What website you are trying to login to (is it an API for example?); what are you are trying to do?

Comment: fiverr.com/login is the site i want to login threw my android app

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the webserver is set up, but as a simple approach, you can make and HTTP POST request, and based on either the http code returned or a message you can tell the user success or fail.

For a code snippet on how to do a POST request you can look at

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient.

You should also be doing this over HTTPS since you are sending a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP request for this purpose.

- Send your soap request with user-name and password parameters.
- In response, you will get the acknowledgment true of false, on basis of which you can show any user friendly message in your android login screen.